# Handler not updating int in real time

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a button that starts a timer (seconds only). Whenever it's pressed, the timer is reset back to 0 and it starts incrementing each second again. Here I have a handler but it doesn't update in realtime, it only updates when you click the button. What am I missing?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    int mSeconds;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        downloadedImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }

    Runnable UpdateRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateSec();
        }
    };

    public void updateSec() {
        mSeconds++;
        mHandler.postDelayed(UpdateRunnable, 1000);
    }

    public void clickAsync(View view) {

        new ImageDownloader().execute(downloadUrl);
        Button button = (Button) view;
        mSeconds = 0;

        button.setText("Seconds since clicked: " + mSeconds);
        //actively increment and update seconds on button every second
        //set seconds to 0 on click
        updateSec();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it only updates when you click the button. What am I missing?

Because `button.setText` called only when `Button` is clicked. call `button.setText` inside `run()` before incrementing `mSeconds`:

```
    public void run() {
        button.setText("Seconds since clicked: " + mSeconds);
        updateSec();
    }
```

and to access `button` outside `clickAsync` method declare it outside `clickAsync` method.

Answer (score 0):

You're only updating the button text with `setText()` in `clickAsync()` but not in any of the methods called when the handler runnable fires.

Consider moving the

```
button.setText("Seconds since clicked: " + mSeconds);
```

inside `updateSec()`.